# jade/pug seperate control flow from templating

Tags: node.js, pug

Isn't it possible to seperate control flow from template? I want to check a few variables if they are null or undefined and in case want to initialize with an empty string. tried like this:

```
meta(property="og:site_name", content=pageData.name)
meta(property="og:title", content=pageData.name)
- var article_id = pageData.article_id
- var ean = pageData.ean
- var color = pageData.color

if article_id == null
  article_id = ""
if ean == null
  ean = ""
if color == null
  color = ""

- var description = pageData.name + " " + article_id + " " + ean + " " + color
meta(name='description', content=description)
meta(property="og:description", content=description)
```

but the last two meta tags will never appear. i assume pug is going into an if and never comes back? but i cant create a control flow for every null variable this would get crazy unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will fix it (adding `-` before setting js variables.

```
meta(property="og:site_name", content=pageData.name)
meta(property="og:title", content=pageData.name)
- var article_id = pageData.article_id
- var ean = pageData.ean
- var color = pageData.color

if article_id == null
  - article_id = ""
if ean == null
  - ean = ""
if color == null
  - color = ""

- var description = pageData.name + " " + article_id + " " + ean + " " + color
meta(name='description', content=description)
meta(property="og:description", content=description)
```

as of separation, if youre using express for example, when you call `res.render` you can send js functions and variables to be sent to the view and used there.

```
res.render('email', {
  pageData: pageData,
  articleId : pageData.article_id || ""
});
```

Comment: great thank you the hyphen fixed it! but what is the effect of the hyphen?

Comment: @Mortiz
`-` will indicate that you are writing javascript, hence you can access article_id from javascript and give it a new value. without it its pug syntax that doesnt mean anything. you can write `- if` to have an if statement in javascript aswell, but pug supports if without `-` to be able to mix javascript with pug to put pug inside if statements etc.